# Does maven expose scmUrl as a property?

Tags: maven-scm, buildnumber-maven-plugin

I'm using maven scm plugin and buildnumber plugin to get set buildNumber property from revision.  I'd like to get the full url as well but it doesn't appear to be exposed as a property.  I know I can call svn info and grep for it but I figured the maven way would be to expose it.

Please let me know if there is a plugin that exposes the url as a property.

For now, I plan to add the functionality to buildNumber plugin and submit a patch.

Thanks

Peter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to modify buildNumber plugin.  [maven-scm-plugin:validate-mojo](http://maven.apache.org/scm/maven-scm-plugin/validate-mojo.html) provides
**${project.scm.connection}**

Comment: Indeed not ! the <url> part of the plugin doesn't seem to be exposed